# How do I stop Excel from rounding numbers when format has been set to number and to 2 decimals?

Tags: formatting, numbering

Sorry for the dumb question:

So in my dataset I put, for example, the number 1.30 down for a patient.
I formatted all cells as numbers, and set the decimal places to 2. However, the number is displayed as 1.3.

I copied my data from a Word file, perhaps that has something to do with what is causing the problem? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: 1.30 & 1.3 are mathematically identical. It's your display formatting that needs to specify 2 decimal places, not the number stored internally.

Comment: That's the weird thing. All numbers in the dataset are formatted as 'numbers' with 'decimals' set to 2. Still, it displays 1 decimal number.
Could it be important that I copied the numbers from word?

Comment: "it displays 1 decimal number"… where? In the formatted cell or in the formula bar? the cell is the only place that is going to be interested in your formatting, the formula bar is not concerned with your formatted output at all, only the underlying number. Imagine your input number was 1.29956. Your output would still be 1.30 to 2 places.

Comment: Sorry that was unclear> It displays 1.3 in the formatted cells as well as in the formula bar.
I edited my question so it is more clear.

Comment: Ah. OK, then idk, sorry.

Comment: What if you take a new worksheet, set the format as Numbers 2 decimals. Then copy the data that is incorrectly displayed from old sheet and paste it as unformatted values into those cells in new sheet?

Comment: Make sure your numbers are numbers. Excel displays exactly 2 decimals in Number cells with 2 decimals: 1 will be displayed as 1.00. I suspect the "1.3" got into the cell as text. Check if there is not an apostrophe before "1.3" when you edit the cell—it is the text marker. Then, focus that single cell, press Ctrl+1 and make sure the format is indeed what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

- Select the cells or column
- In the Home pane, click the arrow next to "Format" and select "Format Cells..."
- In the Number tab, click "Custom"
- Under "Type:" enter `0.00`
- Click OK.

The result will look like:

[image]